# GWT Web App Creator's .launch file: what is it and do I need it?

Tags: java, eclipse, gwt

I just used GWT's [`webAppCreator`](https://developers.google.com/web-toolkit/doc/latest/RefCommandLineTools#webAppCreator) command-line utility, and noticed it produced a `MyModule.launch` file.

**What is this .launch file, why do I need it, and what happens if I delete it?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Files ending in .launch are used to store project specific launch configurations. Normally, when you right click on a resource and select "Run As..." eclipse will store the settings you enter in a location that is specific to your machine, not within your project's working directory. If you want to share or persist your configurations, you have to generate a .launch file.

I suspect that webAppCreator is creating a .launch file to provide you with some sane defaults for launching your project. If you delete the .launch file, eclipse will still be able to launch the project, but you will be responsible for manually configuring the project's arguments and parameters.

Comment: I like to store these profiles in the .settings directory. Eclipse then seems to pick up on these .launch files when you import the project.